# How to read a constant stream of NMEA http data using ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets, stream, gps

I have the iPhone app called 'gps2ip', which launches a web server you can visit to get streaming NMEA data.

You can directly connect to this stream using qgis to get an updated location position on your map. I'd like to access this stream programmatically.

If I type in this into my browser url window: `http://192.168.1.116:11123` where 192.168.1.116 is the ip of my smartphone as indicated by the gps2ip app

I get a constant stream of newline separated NMEA strings on my safari/chrome/mozilla browser screen, constantly being updated at the bottom with constantly new lines of data.

```
    GPS 2 IP Server started. "exit" to finish.
    $GPGGA,005730,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,1,8,0.9,13.6,M,46.9,M,0,2*56
    $GPRMC,005730,A,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,0.00,,120115,003.1,W*66
    $GPGGA,005730,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,1,8,0.9,13.6,M,46.9,M,0,2*56
    $GPRMC,005730,A,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,0.00,,120115,003.1,W*66
    $GPGGA,005731,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,1,8,0.9,13.7,M,46.9,M,0,2*56
    $GPRMC,005731,A,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,0.00,,120115,003.1,W*67
    $GPGGA,005731,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,1,8,0.9,13.7,M,46.9,M,0,2*56
    $GPRMC,005731,A,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,0.00,,120115,003.1,W*67
    $GPGGA,005732,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,1,8,0.9,13.6,M,46.9,M,0,2*54
    $GPRMC,005732,A,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,0.00,,120115,003.1,W*64
    $GPGGA,005732,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,1,8,0.9,13.6,M,46.9,M,0,2*54
    $GPRMC,005732,A,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,0.00,,120115,003.1,W*64
    $GPGGA,005733,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,1,8,0.9,13.5,M,46.9,M,0,2*56
    $GPRMC,005733,A,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,0.00,,120115,003.1,W*65
    $GPGGA,005733,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,1,8,0.9,13.5,M,46.9,M,0,2*56
    $GPRMC,005733,A,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,0.00,,120115,003.1,W*65
    $GPGGA,005734,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,1,8,0.9,13.4,M,46.9,M,0,2*50
    $GPRMC,005734,A,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,0.00,,120115,003.1,W*62
    $GPGGA,005734,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,1,8,0.9,13.4,M,46.9,M,0,2*50
    $GPRMC,005734,A,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,0.00,,120115,003.1,W*62
    $GPGGA,005735,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,1,8,0.9,13.3,M,46.9,M,0,2*56
    $GPRMC,005735,A,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,0.00,,120115,003.1,W*63
    $GPGGA,005735,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,1,8,0.9,13.3,M,46.9,M,0,2*56
    $GPRMC,005735,A,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,0.00,,120115,003.1,W*63
    $GPGGA,005736,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,1,8,0.9,13.2,M,46.9,M,0,2*54
    $GPRMC,005736,A,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,0.00,,120115,003.1,W*60
    $GPGGA,005736,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,1,8,0.9,13.2,M,46.9,M,0,2*54
    $GPRMC,005736,A,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,0.00,,120115,003.1,W*60
    $GPGGA,005737,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,1,8,0.9,13.4,M,46.9,M,0,2*53
    $GPRMC,005737,A,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,0.00,,120115,003.1,W*61
    $GPGGA,005737,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,1,8,0.9,13.4,M,46.9,M,0,2*53
    $GPRMC,005737,A,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,0.00,,120115,003.1,W*61
    $GPGGA,005738,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,1,8,0.9,13.4,M,46.9,M,0,2*5C
    $GPRMC,005738,A,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,0.00,,120115,003.1,W*6E
    $GPGGA,005738,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,1,8,0.9,13.4,M,46.9,M,0,2*5C
    $GPRMC,005738,A,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,0.00,,120115,003.1,W*6E
    $GPGGA,005739,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,1,8,0.9,13.4,M,46.9,M,0,2*5D
    $GPRMC,005739,A,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,0.00,,120115,003.1,W*6F
    $GPGGA,005739,3403.415,N,07914.488,W,1,8,0.9,13.4,M,46.9,M,0,2*5D
```

I know how to parse these lines of NMEA code into latitude/longitude pairs, I just need to be able to access "the last one" easily inside a ruby environment.

I want to be able to pluck the last one or two lines and parse the NMEA strings manually, but I haven't figured out a way to "sip from the firehose" of data without generating an error message.

When I try this:

```
require 'open-uri'
open("http://192.168.1.116:11123")
```

I get this error:

```
Net::HTTPBadResponse: wrong status line: "GPS 2 IP Server started. \"exit\" to finish."
```

Where "GPS 2 IP Server Started. 'exit' to finish." is of course the first line of the response.

What ruby gem should I use to sip from this firehose of data? Apparently open-uri wants html headers and my stream has none of that. I just need to stream pure text apparently.

Comment: The data is evidently not being transferred in the HTTP protocol.

Comment: How fast is this firehose? (like in lines per second)

Comment: 1/s maybe I'm not sure....not exactly I firehose I guess maybe I just wanted to say that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this isn't the HTTP protocol, you'll need the more generic [Socket](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html). You can do something like this:

```
require 'socket'

s = TCPSocket.new '192.168.1.116', 11123

while line = s.gets 
  puts line
end

s.close
```

Depending on how fast the data arrives and how long it takes to process each line, you may need to investigate putting each line into a queue such as [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) so that multiple workers can process lines simultaneously.

Comment: This works great. All I had to do to seal the deal here was set my gps2ip app to broadcast only GPGLL signals, then used some ruby code here: https://github.com/jgillick/ruby-serialgps to parse the strings. Have a very crappy protogem that handles the last leg of the transaction, i.e. returning simple float values for lat & lng. https://github.com/ddd1600/parse_nmea_from_ip

Answer (score 0):

Since what you have is a never-ending stream of data, you can't just grab the last message.  You must consume the stream, and decide when you've received enough to start your processing.  You could probably take advantage of the `GPRMC` message to do that.

In [nmea_plus](https://github.com/ifreecarve/nmea_plus) (full disclosure, I wrote it), you could do it this way:

```
require 'socket'
require 'nmea_plus'

allowable_delay = 3  # threshold to consider the stream as fresh
caught_up = false    # flag to say whether we've crossed the threshold

io_source = TCPSocket.new('192.168.1.116', 11123)
source_decoder = NMEAPlus::SourceDecoder.new(io_source)

source_decoder.each_message do |msg|
  case msg.data_type
  when 'GPRMC'
    if Time.now - msg.utc_time < allowable_delay
      caught_up = true
    end
  when 'GPGLL'
    if caught_up
      puts "Fix: #{msg.latitude}, #{msg.longitude}"
    end
  end
end
```

By default, the decoder ignores any lines that don't parse as NMEA.